# How to change the Day/Night state in Android Auto app?

Tags: android, android-auto

I uploaded an auto app to the play store and My app was rejected due to the

> Your app submission has been rejected for failure to comply with Auto App Quality guidelines. If this submission was an update to an existing app, the version published prior to this update is still available in Google Play. Please review the Auto App Quality guidelines, then modify your app and resubmit. Additional details have been sent to your account owner's email address.

How may I change the day/night mode in android auto app for minimise the user distraction. I googled this and got nothing.

How may I change the theme of auto device?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a set of resources with the `night` qualifier.  Read the docs for [providing resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).